# How long is Android ViewTreeObserver alive?

Tags: android, android-viewtreeobserver

I am working on an app which listens for View events like scrolling, layout drawn using ViewTreeObserver. ViewTreeObserver has a method to check if it's alive before doing anything eg. adding listeners.

I have to reproduce the issue of dead / not alive ViewTreeObserver to see If my code works well in production. I don't see anything in android documentation to reproduce it.

I appreciate any help / pointers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In fact, if you check the source code of class ViewTreeObserver, there is a "kill" function to set mAlive to false, also only here, **but it is never invoked.**

```
/**
 * Marks this ViewTreeObserver as not alive. After invoking this method, invoking
 * any other method but {@link #isAlive()} and {@link #kill()} will throw an Exception.
 *
 * @hide
 */
private void kill() {
    mAlive = false;
}
```

In my opinion, this observer will become unavailable (but is not un-alive, you couldn't use isAlive() to determine current observer's state) after:

1. You removed listener(s), such as
   view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
2. The current activity containing the view is destroyed

Comment: No, It's been invoked in this method "void merge(ViewTreeObserver observer) " of ViewTreeObserver class.

Answer (score 1):

If `getViewTreeObserver` is called before the view is attached, a variable `mFloatingTreeObserver` is returned. When the view is attached the first observer's listeners will be merged with the parent's listeners and the first `getViewTreeObserver` that you obtained will no longer be alive, as `kill()` is called in that `merge` method